# Why does this view tag to include horizontal line crash the app?

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, horizontal-line

When I comment out the view tag the app works fine. When it's included it crashes. Would be glad if someone could help me out.

**custom_info_window.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background_marker"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/distance"
        android:textColor="@color/foreground_marker"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/foreground_marker"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/foreground_marker"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/foreground_marker"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_custom_info_window" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/custom_marker_remove"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground_marker"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**error in android monitor**

```
12-28 00:28:10.580 22344-22344/com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method lq.b
12-28 00:28:10.771 22344-22344/com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder, PID: 22344
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class null
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder.MapsActivity$CustomInfoWindowAdapter.<init>(MapsActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:70)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
    at aai.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
    at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder.MapsActivity$CustomInfoWindowAdapter.<init>(MapsActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:70) 
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source) 
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source) 
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361) 
    at aai.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82) 
    at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-28 00:28:10.827 22344-22379/com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x633d2df0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x61e37940 arg=0x0
12-28 00:28:10.827 22344-22379/com.example.nobodyme.buildingareafinder E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x633d2df0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
```

How else to add the horizontal line or how to fix this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your view tag needs to have a capital `V`

```
  <view
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/foreground_marker"/>
```

should be

```
   <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/foreground_marker"/>
```

seeing this line in your stacktrace:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class null
```

usually mena's there is a problem in your XML file (not in your java code)

Comment: Oh okay cool, now there's another problem the view occupies the whole map fragment area when I give width = match parent ,whereas I just want it to take the size of the max width of the other layout under the Linear parent layout

Comment: Excluding the view tag others behave as expected

Comment: give the `View` tag a width of `"0dip"` and add another attribute : `android:weight="100"`  but this is another question, you should mark this as resolved, then go work on your code and if still stuck post another separate question

Comment: Yea when I tried to accept it said I cannot accept an answer in a min. And second correction doesn't help, there isn't a tag called `android:weight` right? only `android:layout_weight` and making that 100 didn't bring up the window at all!

Comment: And yes i'll post as another, okay

Comment: start by making the parent LinearLayout match_content because thats the way to go, without this at the moment the LinearLayout is as wide as the widest child (in your case the line)

Answer (score 2):

Your tag must be View with capital letter instead of view.
Hope it helps!